# Alternative to train current collectors (pantographs)

Tags: high-power

A [current collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_collector) (or [pantograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantograph_(transport))) is a mechanical system used by, for example, trains and trams, to collect current from an overhead wire.

When thinking about high-speed trains, e.g., the [Shinkansen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinkansen#Technology), but also with lower speed trains, there must be massive wear and tear on the current collectors and the wires.

Because changing the overhead wire is more expensive than replacing the current collector contacts, one chooses a softer material to make the current collector wear down faster than the overhead lines.

I am fascinated by the fact that such a "primitive" way of transferring current is used so successfully, and that it is even possible that a train goes many hundred kilometers without having to change contacts.

**Are there any other alternatives to transfer current for high-speed trains?**

Some trains are using [magnetic levitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maglev), but I believe the tracks are costly because they have to be fitted with strong electric magnets all the way.

**Why are there no attempts to use a contactless transfer of current, for example, couldn't one design an antenna where current sparks from the overhead wire to the antenna?**

*Please suggest better tags for this question.*

Comment: [3rd rail system](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/OsRDBJM33413X29yXnWD-fX6kWrGdEgP1IH-QRwysuBA5pv9tAz5QMt2ApmwtycTEKA1RbkMtsJRtbCcsIcwLQG3oTkH0qrgZ6QD7Bmshe0nW9TROIuz)

Comment: @Andyaka isn't that the same except that the "overhead wire" is on the ground as a third rail? I would assume that wear and tear applies too in this case

Comment: Well, you didn't mention it AND you didn't call the overhead current collector the more acceptable name of *pantograph* so I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: If you are expecting something like wireless charger of phone then it would be a very bad idea.

Comment: What about the second question in bold letters? Can't we use a voltage higher than the breakdown voltage of air and an antenna to collect the lightning?

Comment: @bodokaiser how many trucks crossing the line may also act as an antenna?

Comment: What about using a tesla coil or a capacitive coupling using high-frequency voltage?

Comment: The large arc will totally erode any electrode and cause a massive power loss and possibly melt the wire.

Comment: Why are there no attempts? Because there is no need. The system is very simple, very cheap, and quite efficient.

Comment: 3rd rail is practical at 600V. Less so at 25kV...

Comment: I'm pretty sure at least some maglev trains also use the magnetic field to couple power to the train. Could be wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This blog](https://maxfaqs.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/when-good-trains-go-bad-pantograph-edition/) says the wear lifetime is several months for the carbon "shoes" on the pantograph. Graphite carbon is itself a fairly good lubricant, so the friction is comparatively low. The system is incredibly simple and doesn't require too much fancy equipment per km of rail.

The problem with arcing is that it actually causes quite a lot of wear! So much so that it can be used as a machining technique: [Electrical discharge machining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_discharge_machining). It also wastes a chunk of energy in the arc that goes to heating the air.

The "high frequency" Tesla coil approach would require an efficient means of generating high-frequency current at very high power levels (megawatts). While I don't think it's impossible, it feels like it would have high losses, and I'm not sure what level of radiated EMI it would produce given that it's the same architecture as an AM radio transmitter?

Comment: On straight sections of track the overhead line zig-zags from left to right to maintain tension but also to spread the wear across the pantograph. On curves this happens naturally as the contact wire is in straight sections forming a section of a polyhedron and, again, wiping across the pantograph. On some systems there will be a "COAST" signboard to instruct the driver to set the power off while the pantograph runs across a section insulator to minimise arcing and wear.

Comment: Secondary problem with arcing: it's loud.

Comment: EDM: more than just a music genre!